# If a matrix of order n satisfies a monic polynomial of degree n in a algebraically closed field is the polynomial characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a  complex matrix of order 3 satisfies a polynomial of degree 3  is the polynomial characteristic  polynomial  for all such matrix?

Answer (score 3):

The matrix with every entry zero, $O$, satisfies $X(X+1)(X+2)$ but its characteristic polynomial is $X^3$.